# Getter Setter for class

Tags: c++

I was working on homework that my instructor wanted me to write a class named Species with setter and getter functions. I wrote that code but I can't set or get any value when I run it. Can you help me?

```
class Species
{
private:
    string name;
    string country;
    int population;
    int growthrate;
public:
    int year;
    void setName(string NameS){
        NameS=name;
    }
    void setCountry(string CountryS){
        CountryS=country;
    }
    void setPopulation(int pop){
        pop=population;
    }
    void setGrowthRate(int GrowRth){
        GrowRth=growthrate;
    }
    void setYear(int syear){
        syear=year;
    }
    string getName() {
        return name;
    }
    string getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }
    int getGrowthrate() {
        return growthrate;
    }
    double e=2.71828182;
    double calculatePopulation() {
    int b=growthrate*year;
    int a=pow(e,b);
    return population*a;
        }
};
```

Comment: In your setters, please change the order if assignments, e.g. ```
void setCountry(string CountryS) { country = CountryS; }```

Comment: Although you've been requested to do this, I would say as a word of warning that it can be bad practice to do the above. Ideally a constructor should handle all of this, as changes to population should probably be insulated in the class.

Answer (score 3):

First of all. Your class has fields like:

```
    string name;
    string country;
    int population;
    int growthrate;
```

And your methods are like:

```
    void setName(string NameS){
        NameS=name;
    }
```

So you want to set NameS value to the name which makes no sense.
You should assign the field like `name` to be equal to `nameS` not the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a setter should look like this.

```
void setVariable(const VariableType& var){
    this->var=var;
}
```

What you did was `var=this->var`.

Btw, you should make your getter-s `const`

Answer (score -1):

You should use **"this"** keyword to set the value to object of the class.
**this:** to refer current class instance variable. The this keyword can be used to refer current class instance variable.

for example:

```
void setName(string name){
        this->name=name;
    }


void setGrowthRate(int growthrate){
        this->growthrate=growthrate;
```

"this" is very helpful  in  please learn more about it.

Comment: Since it's c++ `this` returns pointer. So if you really want to do it this way the arrow operator is best choice. `this->name=name`

Comment: oh yes sorry about that, use "this->"